# Some Thing that I Can't Figure Out

Tags: java

Here are two similar code.

```
private static void div(String[] args) {
    if (args.length != 3) {
        System.out.println("Error: Argument count mismatch");
        return;
    }
    int Quotient = 0; 
    int Remainder = 0;
    if (isInteger(args[1]) && isInteger(args[2])) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(args[2]) == 0) {
            System.out.println("Undefined");
            return;
        }
        Quotient = Integer.parseInt(args[1]) / Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        Remainder = Integer.parseInt(args[1]) % Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error: Argument type mismatch");
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("Quotient " + Quotient);
    System.out.println("Remainder " + Remainder);
}


private static void div(String[] args) {
    if (args.length != 3) {
        System.out.println("Error: Argument count mismatch");
        return;
    }
    int quotient = 0; 
    int remainder = 0;
    if (isInteger(args[1]) && isInteger(args[2])) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(args[2]) == 0) {
            System.out.println("Undefined");
            return;
        }
        quotient = Integer.parseInt(args[1]) / Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        remainder = Integer.parseInt(args[1]) % Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error: Argument type mismatch");
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("quotient " + quotient);
    System.out.println("remainder " + remainder);
}
```

When  perform a checkstyle audit, the first one have problem with the name, it will shows that

MyCLIParser.java:98:13: Name 'Quotient' must match pattern '`^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$`'.
MyCLIParser.java:99:13: Name 'Remainder' must match pattern '`^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$`'.

However, it is correct when using Automatic grading, the only problem is the codestyle.

The second one's codestyle is right, but after changing the names into quotient and remainder, it has problem when using the Automatic grading. I am sure that all of the relevant names are changed. So why does it happen?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the automatic grading. But if it insists on a specific casing for fields, then you can only complain to the organisation running that service. I dont see a reason that fixing the casing (if you do it everywhere and do not introduce new shadowing, which cannot be seen in your partial example) would make the program wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make this the output code:

```
System.out.println("Quotient " + quotient);
System.out.println("Remainder " + remainder);
```

I am guessing that the auto-grader, similar to ones I've seen before, grades on the basis of the output. You did lowercase `quotient` and `remainder` as local variable names which made checkstyle happy, but you also lowercased them in the output.

Your initial version that checkstyle dislikes but the autograder approves will output the following for 16/3:

```
Quotient 5
Remainder 1
```

while your new version's output is lowercased:

```
quotient 5
remainder 1
```

That is probably why the autograder chokes and rejects it. All that checkstyle would apply to is the naming of variables and the actual logic, not the format or capitalization of any string *literals* or the output. Did you happen to use a find-and-replace over the entire file?

Comment: @AliceBobCatherineDough OK, so does the autograder accept your solution when you don't change the capitalization of the output?

Comment: Ok, @AliceBobCatherineDough if this answer helped you please mark the check mark next to it so that other users are aware that it solved your inquiry.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your last sentence. How can I not change the output? Do you mean not change System.out.println("Quotient " + Quotient)?

Comment: @AliceBobCatherineDough I highly recommend using a Java IDE such as Eclipse. It will provide support for changing variable names without a blind textual find-and-replace.

Comment: Oh, I change the System.out.println("Quotient " + Quotient) into System.out.println("Quotient " + quotient) and it accept. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You're not changing *all* of the relevant names. Java convention is that classes start with an uppercase letter and that variables, methods, and packages start with lowercase letters, which is why Checkstyle is complaining. Changing those to match convention is the best thing to do, but if you're really replacing all of the instances, there won't be any change in function.

Comment: That is not correct, OP *is* changing all the relevant names, and functionality (by making too many changes).

Comment: But I used the Find tab to replace all match cases?

Comment: @AliceBobCatherineDough Correct, and by doing that you also modified string literals in the output of the program. Please try the suggestion given in my answer.